# How do I move a subtree to another file

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode I frequently want to move one (top-level) tree to another file. I can do this by first calling `org-cut-special` (C-c C-x C-w) in the source file, then switching to the target file and calling `org-yank` (C-y) there. But this is rather tedious.

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: `org-refile`:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-copy.html#Refile-and-copy  See also a reddit discussion regarding setting the depth, etc.:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4366f9/how_do_orgrefiletargets_work/?st=k5lavqh2&sh=571ac002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. I suspected that `org-refile` was the way to go (thanks @lawlist), but I couldn't get it to refile a tree at the topmost (i.e., headline) level.

I turns out that I need to do this:

```
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
```

That allows me to refile at the top level.